# How Can I Display The Current Rating?

Tags: php, rating-system

I was wondering if someone could post for me the changes I need to make to this code to get the current rating values to display on the page before the form is submitted as well as after, as it is written now. Thanks.

```
<?php echo '<html>
<head>
<title>Rating Tool Test</title>
</head>
<body>';
if ( (!isset($_POST['submit'])) ) { 
echo '<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">
Your Rating: <select name="rate">'; 
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { 
echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>"; } 

echo '</select><br /><input type="submit" value="Rate it!" name="submit"/>
   </form>';
} 
else  { 
$rate = isset ($_POST['rate']) ? $_POST['rate'] : 0;
$filename = "ratings";
$alreadyRated = false;
$totalRates = 0;
$totalPoints = 0;

$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$oldResults = file('results/'.$filename.'.txt');
foreach ($oldResults as $value) {
$oneRate = explode(':',$value);
if ($ip == $oneRate[0]) $alreadyRated = true;      
$totalRates++;
$totalPoints += $oneRate[1];
}
if ((!$alreadyRated) && ($rate > 0)){            
$f = fopen('results/'.$filename.".txt","a+");         
fwrite($f,$ip.':'.$rate."\n");
fclose($f);
$totalRates++;
$totalPoints+=$rate;
}
echo 'Total Average Rating:<br />'.substr(($totalPoints/$totalRates),0,3).' Out Of 5.<br />Total Votes: '.$totalRates.'<br />';
for ($i=0;$i<round(($totalPoints/$totalRates),0);$i++){
echo '<img src="style/star.gif" alt="star" />';
}
echo '</body>
</html>';       
} 
?>
```

Comment: What does the above code do wrong?  Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: any chance you could fix the indenting?

Comment: I don't know why this was closed. Not only was the question clear, but I was able to answer it below. Currently his code displays ratings after a form submit. He wanted the ratings to be displayed before and after the form submit, as he stated.

Comment: I guess I just had it in the wrong spot huh. Thank you, I still have much to learn....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes you requested:

```
<?php echo '<html>
<head>
<title>Rating Tool Test</title>
</head>
<body>';
if ( (!isset($_POST['submit'])) ) {
    echo '<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">
        Your Rating: <select name="rate">';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>"; }

        echo '</select><br /><input type="submit" value="Rate it!" name="submit"/>
        </form>';
}
$rate = isset ($_POST['rate']) ? $_POST['rate'] : 0;
$filename = "ratings";
$alreadyRated = false;
$totalRates = 0;
$totalPoints = 0;

$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$oldResults = file('results/'.$filename.'.txt');
foreach ($oldResults as $value) {
    $oneRate = explode(':',$value);
    if ($ip == $oneRate[0]) $alreadyRated = true;
    $totalRates++;
    $totalPoints += $oneRate[1];
}
if ((!$alreadyRated) && ($rate > 0)){
    $f = fopen('results/'.$filename.".txt","a+");
    fwrite($f,$ip.':'.$rate."\n");
    fclose($f);
    $totalRates++;
    $totalPoints+=$rate;
}
echo 'Total Average Rating:<br />'.substr(($totalPoints/$totalRates),0,3).' Out Of 5.<br />Total Votes: '.$totalRates.'<br />';
for ($i=0;$i<round(($totalPoints/$totalRates),0);$i++){
    echo '<img src="style/star.gif" alt="star" />';
}
echo '</body></html>';
?>
```